# Can I create different row numbers inside two columns using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, layout, grid

First of all, this is my first topic and I would like to greet you all and in advance thank you for all your help. I am a programming newbie. I started learning python a few months ago and now I'm trying to make (and I did it) a functional GUI for a friend, but my "customer" has some layout wishes and I'm having trouble arranging it the way he wants me to. This is how I need it to look like:

[image]

Basically, if I know how to create different row numbers inside two columns, I might even do it by myself. I've searched online but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I don't see any row numbers in your image. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't want to limit anyone with an idea with my own choice of row numbers, I wanted experienced people to give me their best solution to the problem. But let's say like this:

-Two columns:
    Left column contains entry widget and listboxes (which are in their labelframes). Total of 4 rows
    Right column contains these buttons and spinboxes. So it should have around 7 rows in right column. 

I hope I managed to express myself better now.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want physical row numbers, you just want two columns with a different number of rows in each.

Comment: Yeah. That would help me a lot. I've came close to the solution, but it's too much walking on foot. It would help a lot if there was an easier way to do it than how I did it.

Comment: @py_noob_py Just a random question, have you tried using a frame to arrange your GUI elements ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. I used the grid method in tkinter. I've gotten the solution it just took me to make too much rows and columns so that I could position everything the way i wanted. I made like a table of 8 rows and 7 columns in order to get where I need. And that looks a bit messy because I don't need that much rows in left column, so I had to use columnspan for my listboxes in the left column. Sorry if I'm hard to understand, but I'm still learning all this and can't still have the conversation like a pro, but I need help haha :)

Comment: You only need 4 rows and 2 columns at your root level. On the left, do the widgets one by one. On the right, start with row 1 and create a frame that spans across 2 rows, and create the Spinbox/buttons inside that frame. And lastly put the logo at the remaining row.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest widget management tools by using the Frame widget.

```
root = tk.Tk()
left_side = tk.Frame(root)
right_side = tk.Frame(root)
left_side.grid(row=0, column=0)
right_side.grid(row=0, column=1)

entrybox = tk.Entry(left_side, ...args...)
listbox1 = tk.Entry(left_side, ditto)
listbox2 = tk.Entry(left_side, etc)
listbox3 = tk.Entry(left_side, yeah)
entrybox.grid(row=0, column=0)
listbox1.grid(row=2, column=0)
listbox2.grid(row=3, column=0)
listbox3.grid(row=4, column=0)

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(right_side, . . . )
< all those things >
spinbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
the_next_one.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

that's just an example, and I left a lot to be filled in, but I hope that shows you what I am talking about

You can also use columnspan and rowspan, take a good look at this page:  https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm
You could have that top listbox span 5 or 6 rows and put all the buttons on the right in those rows but in the right column.

Hope that helps, feel free to ask questions or for more examples!